# Need to make my android application interact with a site I own and run

Tags: android, client

I need to make my app access my website and modify it when it gets new input. I've had people say use JSON or XML, and I know how to use xml files, but how would I make my app use and modify the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Expose the functionality of your website as REST service calls that your app on the phone can use to query and modify the data.

Comment: I don't know what you said. Googled REST and I saw a wikipedia article. This seems to be the functionality I want though, but how can I implement it?

Comment: Looks like it might be time to bone up on RESTful APIs. There's a load of resources out there if you search that term.